# Variable selection methods in survival analysis

Tags: survival-analysis

I am using two models for my research. One is the coxph regression model and other is survival trees. I have found the scikit-survival package in python which is able to identify contributing variables and also rank them, but there is no reference to the papers.

I am looking for latest(published after 2010) research papers which implement variable selection methods specifically for survival analysis and if possible their GitHub links. I tried looking up papers but all I can find are papers which are published way before and there are not many citations for those papers. Can someone please provide me with the papers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about the lasso cox? you can do it in R with the package glmnet